# How to query a (almost) tree structure

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I got this table:

```
id   replacement id
1     2
2     1
2     3
3     2
2     4
4     2
10    11
11    10
```

The id(objects) are in a tree structure but the table is designed poorly for a tree structure.
The connection between the nodes goes both ways.

The only way to determine if one is the parent of another is this table:

```
id  valid_until
1
2   2014-01-01
3   2013-01-01
4   2013-01-01
10  
11  2014-01-01
```

2 is parent of 3 and 4 because its valid_until is later than 3 and 4. 1 is top node because it's still valid.

I'm struggling to write a query of this data so it could look like this:

```
id  parent
1
2   1
3   2
4   2
```

Is there a way to make this as a single query or do I've to create a procedure and a temporary view for this?

**EDIT: I added some new rows to my table. So basically I also want to say in the query that I only want id: 1,2,3 or 4's tree not 10 and 11. How do I do that?**

Comment: Will 1 always be the only node that has `valid_until` null?

Comment: I think there could be instances where 1 is not the only node where valid_until is null. But to make it simple for now. Yes, 1 is the only node that can have its valid_until null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer answers the follow up question of only getting the records that belongs to a particular root node:

```
select id, parent_id, level
from (
select aid id, case when adate = to_date('9999','yyyy') then null else rid end parent_id
from (select
   c.aid,
   c.rid,
   c.adate,
   nvl(b.d,to_date('9999','yyyy')) bdate from (select a.id aid, a.rid rid, nvl(d,to_date('9999','yyyy')) adate from a, b where a.id = b.id) c, b where c.rid = b.id
) where adate < bdate or adate = to_date('9999','yyyy')
) 
 START WITH id =1  -- ID of the ROOT node
connect by prior id = parent_id
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work

```
create table a (id number, rid number);

insert into a values(1,2);
insert into a values(2,1);
insert into a values(2,3);
insert into a values(3,2);
insert into a values(2,4);
insert into a values(4,2);

create table b (id number, d date);

insert into b values(1, null);
insert into b values(2, to_date('2014-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into b values(3, to_date('2013-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into b values(4, to_date('2013-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'));

select aid id, case when adate = to_date('9999','yyyy') then null else rid end parent_id
from (
   select
     c.aid,
     c.rid,
     c.adate,
     nvl(b.d,to_date('9999','yyyy')) bdate 
   from (
         select a.id aid, a.rid rid, nvl(d,to_date('9999','yyyy')) adate 
         from a, b where a.id = b.id
         ) c, b 
          where c.rid = b.id
      ) where adate < bdate or adate = to_date('9999','yyyy')
order by id
```

Comment: Hi again, I added an additional problem to my original problem. Do you mind reviewing it?

Comment: You can do this by adding a hierarchal traverse of the three. I also added a indicator of the level. This require that you know the root node id: